# Internet slows and eventually stops when connected through VPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn

When I connect to my internet via wifi the connection is fine and stable, and when I connect a VPN via openVPN it works well for a period. However, after I have used it for some time the connection slows and then ceases. If I then reestablish the VPN it will continue to work but again, will again slow and stop. The connection drops faster when I'm doing heavy downloading so it would seem to be an issue with some data limit. I've checked with my provider and they say it's not an issue with them, and I'm inclined to believe them as I have no issues with any other devices.